# Django Rest Framework upload_to doesn't work as desired

Tags: python, django

I'm passing callable for image field in my project like this

```
def profile_picture_path(instance, filename):
    """Path for uploading profile pictures in media directory"""
    return f"user/profile_picture/{instance.pk}/{filename}"

class User(AbstractUser):
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(_("profile picture"),
                                        upload_to=profile_picture_path,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
```

When I add a user through the admin panel, the image gets a proper path: `user/profile_picture/3/pfp.png`. Problem comes when I send a post request to registrate: `user/profile_picture/None/pfp.png`

```
# views.py

@api_view(["POST"])
def register_view(request):
    """
    Register View which takes only post method.
    """
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    else:
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

```
# serializers.py

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exclude = kwargs.pop("exclude", None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if exclude is not None:
            for field_name in exclude:
                self.fields.pop(field_name)

    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        exclude = ["deleted", "deleted_by_cascade"]
```

How can I fix this and get correct path for image uploads?

Comment: I think Its happening because you are trying to add instance PK before your records is being created so its returning none.

Comment: ```return f"user/profile_picture/{instance}/{filename}"```, this one assigns username correctly, so instance gets created at this point, but I need its pk

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Smit Parmar ist right, but it don't solve your question.
At First you should create User ohne Image. After that you can save User with Image.

Cause is your Special profile_picture_path.

If you can save Image Not in User ID Folder, thats works normally.

Comment: The instance itself is defined when this function is called. I tried using just `instance` instead of `instance.pk` and it returns me its `str()` value. The problem is that I can't get the user id inside that function, but an instance of the user itself is available. Also note that when I create a user from the admin site, the user gets the correct profile picture path, but it doesn't work in my register view.